# How to get list of units in a Delphi Compiled Package (.dcp file)

Tags: delphi, package, delphi-7

Is there a way to list what units/classes are in a Delphi compiled package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a new package, add your .dcp to its requires clause, add a new unit to it and use code completion in the uses clause - it will show you all available units in all required packages. If your .dcp is the only required package and you set it to display sorted by scope (right-click in the dropdown) then the units from your .dcp should be on top.

I'm not sure if this works in Delphi 7 already. It works in Delphi 2007.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't actually work in Delphi 7, but I'm making this the accepted answer anyway because it at least works in newer versions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have you had a look at the TDUMP utility that is shipped with Delphi 7? A bpl is just a fancy DLL so you can list its exported functions:

e.g.

"C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin\TDUMP.EXE" AFWRTL_RD7.bpl

Turbo Dump  Version 5.0.16.12 Copyright (c) 1988, 2000 Inprise Corporation

```
              Display of File AFWRTL_RD7.BPL
```

. . .

Exports from AFWRTL_RD7.bpl

91 exported name(s), 91 export addresse(s).  Ordinal base is 1.

...

```
000046B4   31 000A __fastcall Fgint::Base2StringToFGInt(System::AnsiString, Fgint::TFGInt&)
```

...

If you look at the exported functions, the name of the function seems to be prefixed with the unit or dependent package name, e.g. Fgint::Base2StringToFGInt is function Base2StringToFGInt in unit Fgint.pas.

Alternatively, have a look at the depends.exe utility that ships with the Windows Resource Kit. This provides a GUI to view the contents of a DLL (or BPL).

See

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=49ae8576-9bb9-4126-9761-ba8011fabf38&displaylang=en

for more details.

Vince

Comment: Thanks I did consider TDump until I realised that it's a DCP i want to peek into not a BPL. Unfortunately I do not have the BPL. +1 for the suggestion anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Besides asking the developer or reading the documentation, the answer is No.

Answer (score 0):

[JCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/) "uses expert" can show a lot right in the IDE.